# VB6 Subclassing: How to detect [ALT] + mouse left click in window title/caption bar

Tags: vb6, subclass

I need to subclass a VB6 form so that if the user hits the [ALT] key while left clicking the title/caption bar, I can do something custom (show dialog box, file io, whatever).

So far, I have been able to do the subclassing in my NewWndProc() to correctly trap the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message when wParam = HTCAPTION, but I don't know how to trap the [ALT] key at the same time.

I have used the SPY utility a bit to check for messages, but I still can't solve this.  Thanks for any help.

**Update:**
Looks like I may have to use mouse and keyboard hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's not sent as part of the message. but you can call [`GetKeyState(VK_MENU)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get whether it's pressed or not.

Comment: That was it. I also experimented with WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK and also using GetAsyncKeyState( ).  The solution also involves setting a flag to ~NOT~ run the default WndProc after I fall out of the Select Case that traps these 2 WM_NCLBUTTONxxx msgs.  Thanks for the hint that got me there.